# Setting static background image in local Django environment

Tags: django

I am trying to build my first Django project from scratch and am having difficulty setting the background image.  I am new to programming in general so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I have read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles) on static file implementations and various stack overflow posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451352/cant-figure-out-serving-static-images-in-django-dev-environment) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057982/django-static-files-while-debug-mode-is-on) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148738/cannot-get-images-to-display-in-simple-django-site)) on setting the background image, but I still can't get it to work.

I have:

- installed the django.contrib.staticfiles as an installed app.
- added this to the settings file:

  `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.debug",
  "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
  "django.core.context_processors.media",
  "django.core.context_processors.static",
  "django.core.context_processors.tz",
  "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
  )`
- set the Static_Root and Static_URL files to STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/user_name/development/projects/ecollar_site/static/' and '/static/' respectively
- put this code at the end of my URLs file:

  ```
  `if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += patterns('',
  (r'^/static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
  {'/ecollar_site/': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
  'show_indexes' : True}),
  )`
  ```
- ran `python manage.py collectstatic`
- and then put this line in the CSS file.

  `body{ font:16px/26px Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;   background-image: url("{{ STATIC_URL }}img/IMG_0002.jpg"); }`

I know the static files bit is working because the CSS is loaded.  And I can change the background color by using background-color: blue.  But the static image is simply not being put as the background image.  Have I made a rookie mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css file is not rendered by Django template engine and so {{ STATIC_URL }} is not being replaced. You'll have to use /static/img/IMG_0002.jpg in the CSS file or move that bit of CSS in your html file's style tag.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I've changed the CSS file but it's still not working.  Should I have to change anything else?

Comment: solved it with your advice.  I just forgot to use url() around the /static/img/IMG_0002.jpg.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static_media/'
```

urly.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
    (r'^static_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 
        'serve', {
        'document_root': '/path/to/static_media',
        'show_indexes': True }),)
```

your css and jquery on template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}base_min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

If your are using production version try this

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://media.example.org/'


Development: /static_media/base_min.css
Production: http://media.example.org/base_min.css
```

Hope this will  help  you

Don't forget to attached `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` in your INSTALLED_APPS